# Gather verb is not working for 1st participant in conference only work for last connected participant

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, conference

basically I want to connect third participant (A PSTN no) on ongoing call when conference owner press a key

here is my Twiml :-

```
    <Response>
       <Dial hangupOnStar="true">
         <Conference">PSTNConf</Conference>
       </Dial>
       <Gather action="/action/url" digits="1"/>
    </Response>
```

this is work fine till second participant not connect when second participant join the conference Gather verb is not work for 1st participant

I want both participants in a conference then Conference owner (1st participant) decided to add third participant using gather verb

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) cannot actually work with a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference). You can only nest [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say), [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) or [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pause) within a `<Gather>` element.

The nearest you can get to this is to include the [`hangupOnStar="true"` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar) on the `<Dial>` element as well as an [`action` URL.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) Then, when one of your callers presses `*` they will drop out of the conference and Twilio will request the `action` URL, you can then return TwiML including a `<Gather>` if you want to take more input, or just use the webhook to dial another caller into the conference.

If you complete the action by returning TwiML that dials the caller back into the original conference, then they will rejoin and continue.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but same thing "hangupOnStar" only work if second participant not in conference if second participant join in conference then  "hangupOnStar" not work 

actually what I am doing twilio client start a conference then I used rest api to add second participant   in same conference

<Response>
  <Dial hangupOnStar="true" action="/action/url">
   <Conference>PSTNConf</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>

Comment: What do you mean hangupOnStar doesn't work when there's two people in the conference? What happens?

Comment: on star press action url not received any event  when both participants in conference  and  first participant  (conference owner) press star 
but it work if second participants not in conference

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug then. I would get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide some Call SIDs where this happened so that the support team can track down what is going on.